# Creating a file that contains the set of inputs in pyqt

Tags: pyqt4

I have created a widget with a text bix, a combo box, a checkbox and some pushbottons. I wish to make a record of the set of input given everytime in a file. how do I do that ? Pls suggest.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and not that bad way imho is by reading the values and serializing them using json. You have to set/get the values individually for each input (with different calls). It's a breeze in fact. Personally, I have made my own 'serializing' function so I keep references to all objects in a list and that function loops the list serializing everything.
Depending on your needs and the complexity of your project you may need something different. Why don't you share some more details?
Best Regards.